# Как делают авторизацию через json?

Tags: javascript, json, rest

Есть задача сделать авторизацию на сайте через json, суть в том, что сервер отдает строку json при запросе, после введения данных в форму. В строке json есть ключ - токен, роль юзера. Вот получил я эту строку, что дальше? Расскажите схематично. Первое, что мне пришло на ум - это писать всю строку в куки и перед каждым действием ajax запросом сравнивать токен, но ведь это нагрузка на сервер, если нет, то поправьте меня. Копнул дальше, наткнулся на REST API, вроде как то, что нужно, но опять же, в чем разница между простым json api и как реализовать авторизацию?

Comment: Права доступа чудесным образом не проверяться. Их надо в любом случае проверять при каждом обращении. Так что единственный путь - это выбрать способ максимально быстро проверить токен. Например зашифровать в сам токен всю требуемую информацию о клиенте, возможно дополнив ее некой контрольной суммой, которую может вычислить только ваш сервер. При получении обращения расшифровываете токен и сверяете контрольную сумму. Если корректная, значит информации о клиенте в токене можно доверять

Comment: Вчитался в ваш текст ... у меня ощущение, что вы путаете стороны. Клиент получив от сервера один раз токен, да, должен его где то у себя сохранить. Далее он просто отправляет этот токен на сервер при любом обращении. И да, с куками отправка будет происходить автоматически. Но сверять что либо на клиенте перед ajax запросами бесполезно. Все проверки на валидность токена должны происходить на стороне сервера

Comment: @Mike, а что с нагрузкой на сервер, может если в системе будут 100 пользователей, то это будет незаметно для сервера, а если 1000 и больше?

Comment: Смотря как сделаете. Выбирайте не очень тяжелые алгоритмы шифрования. Если они все таки тяжелые, всегда можно попробовать закешировать нужные данные, например в Redis (который держит по некоторым тестам 80000 запросов get в секунду на серверах начального уровня). И повторяю: другого пути просто не существует. Любые проверки на стороне браузера любой желающий спокойно поправит и они отработают так как ему нужно

Comment: @Mike, понял, спасибо за разъяснение